# npm ERR! Invalid name: "@angular/core" when following the Angular 2 Quick Start

Tags: angular, npm-install

I am trying to follow the [Angular 2 Quick Start](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#) and one of the first steps is to setup the environment. I am not completely new to npm - I managed to install and try out Ember, but that's about it.

Below is the package.json file I created (copied from the above link).
When I run `npm install` here is what I get.
The quick start says I should **not** see any npm ERR! lines.

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.12
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 No repository field.
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3

npm ERR! Invalid name: "@angular/core"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/john/development/angular/angular2-quickstart/npm-debug.log
```

additional tries just give me more of the same:

```
$ npm install
npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v5.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.3

npm ERR! Invalid name: "@angular/router-deprecated"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/john/development/angular/angular2-quickstart/npm-debug.log
```

Here is the full traceback from the npm-debug.log if that helps anyone:

```
60 verbose stack Error: Invalid name: "@angular/core"
60 verbose stack     at ensureValidName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:302:15)
60 verbose stack     at Object.module.exports.fixNameField (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/fixer.js:206:5)
60 verbose stack     at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:29:38
60 verbose stack     at Array.forEach (native)
60 verbose stack     at normalize (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/node_modules/normalize-package-data/lib/normalize.js:28:15)
60 verbose stack     at final (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:338:5)
60 verbose stack     at then (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:113:5)
60 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/read-package-json/read-json.js:284:20)
60 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16)
60 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:324:13)
61 verbose cwd /home/john/development/angular/angular2-quickstart
62 error Linux 3.13.0-85-generic
63 error argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "@angular/core"
64 error node v5.10.1
65 error npm  v3.8.3
66 error Invalid name: "@angular/core"
67 error If you need help, you may report this error at:
67 error     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
68 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",

    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",

    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.7",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^0.8.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried installing Angular myself using your package.json and didn't run into any problems. Can you run `npm install @angular/core` and see if it gives you any errors?

Comment: I got the same message as shown above.

Comment: I did a little search and I found [this](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon/issues/280). The problem could be in your npm version.

Comment: I saw that one also, but seemed kind of old version wise. I had tried "npn -v" and got  3.8.3, even did as suggested in that link, "node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm --version" got 3.8.3.  but still, it did seem like in the end it was some how version dependent, so I did "sudo npm install -g npm"  which brought me up to 3.8.8 .  After that npm install worked! I got a few warning, but I think they make sense.  If you elaborate a bit on your suggestion in the form of an answer, I will accept it.  - either way thanks!

Comment: Weird - I'm getting this problem with all npm versions I've tried. 3.8.3 as well as 3.9.3. I'm using n for node version management. Not sure if that plays into it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since my comment answered this question I will provide it in the form of an answer for the future people visiting this page.

After a little Googling I found two pages having the same problem; [page 1](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon/issues/280) and [page 2](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8927). It seems there's a bug in some versions of NPM so simply upgrading to a newer version should fix the problem:

`sudo npm install -g npm`

Downgrading could also fix the problem:

`sudo npm install -g npm@<version here>`

Hope this helps

Comment: If you have super old version of NPM like me, you may need to reinstall.  In my case I had to just [download the installer and reinstall node.](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Answer (score 3):

You just have to update your npm version

```
npm install -g npm
```

Comment: I stumbled on this because I am using the 'n' node version manager. To update npm in this scenario I had to run `curl -0 -L http://npmjs.org/install.sh | sudo sh`. (taken from [here](https://github.com/tj/n))