# invalid name @angular/common : npm

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying Ionic2, but am getting some error while trying to install default npm packages for Ionic2. I tried to run the following command and getting the error below:

`npm install @angular/common` [like here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/common)

[image]

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37038269/npm-err-invalid-name-angular-core-when-following-the-angular-2-quick-start) solution but getting the same error.

package.json file content:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router": "^2.0.0-rc.1",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-beta.7",
    "ionic-native": "^1.1.0",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "2.2.0",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "gulp-watch": "4.3.5",
    "ionic-gulp-browserify-es2015": "^1.1.0",
    "ionic-gulp-fonts-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-html-copy": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-sass-build": "^1.0.0",
    "ionic-gulp-scripts-copy": "^2.0.0",
    "run-sequence": "1.1.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: Which version of NodeJS are you using ?

Comment: maybe try `npm clear cache` and then re run `npm install` after restarting the terminal.

Comment: @Adrien i am using the latest version of nodejs

Comment: @candidJ tried that as well same error

Answer (score 2):

try this command

```
npm install -g npm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one may help you :-

```
npm install @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1 --save
```

or you can mention version which you want

Comment: have your `package.json` file has entry for @angular/common ? if yes than remove first than reRun same command

Comment: same error : here is the log (11 verbose mapToRegistry no registry URL found in name for scope @angular)

Comment: please update your question with your package.json file

Comment: your code seems absolutely right without any error, last option try using `"@angular/common": "^2.0.0-rc.1"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112850/discussion-between-ravimittal-and-pardeep-jain).

Answer (score 0):

I also getting same error lot of times. So that I moved angular2 pack instead 
   of @angular pack.

This is my package.json

```
{
"name": "Angular2",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"postinstall": "npm run typings install",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"lite": "lite-server",
"start": "concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
"typings": "typings"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"angular-ui-sortable": "0.13.4",
"angular2": "2.0.0-beta.15",
"angular2-grid": "~0.4.0",
"bootstrap": "3.3.6",
"cli-width": "^2.0.0",
"dragula": "^3.6.8",
"es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
"moment": "2.11.2",
"ng2-bootstrap": "1.0.5",
"ng2-bs3-modal": "0.2.1",
"ng2-ckeditor": "1.0.0",
"ng2-datepicker": "0.6.2",
"ng2-dragula": "^1.1.5",
"ng2-easy-table": "0.0.10",
"ng2-table": "1.0.0-beta.0",
"ng2-translate": "1.11.0",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
"systemjs": "0.19.24",
"zone.js": "0.6.12",
"ng2-img-cropper":"0.2.2",
"ng2-dnd":"1.4.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.0.0",
"lite-server": "^2.1.0",
"typescript": "^1.8.7",
"typings": "^0.7.5",
"cli-width": "^2.0.0"
}
}
```